# GPIO button pressing in C

Tags: c, embedded

I'm relatively new in the embedded world, so I may be a little newbie asking this.

I'm having trouble to understand the syntax of an example program in C that checks if a button is pressed and then turning a LED on if so. I'm using a STM32F207VCT6 (Cortex-M3) microcontroller.

The part of the program that I'm having trouble to understand is the following:

```
if(!(GPIOA->IDR & (1<<4)))
  Key=1;
```

Port 4 from `GPIOA` is set to be an input with pull-up register. The signal from the button goes to GND once it's pressed. `IDR` is the input data register.

So my question is:

I don't understand in this code why the NOT symbol, `!`, inside the `if` statement is needed. And I do not know what comparison is being made inside the `if`, since there is no sign of equal. Can someone help me with that?

PS: I already know that `(1<<4)` is the bit-wise operation for left shifting the bit 1 four times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 16 pins per port in the STM32F207VCT6. This operation is trying to determine the state of a single pin, number 4, of port A. Let's expand each part to better understand what is going on.

We start with the expression:

```
if(!(GPIOA->IDR & (1<<4)))
```

We're working with a 16-bit number to account for the 16 pins. Expanding this we get:

```
if(!(GPIOA->IDR & ((0000 0000 0000 0001) << 4)))
```

You already know that `<<` is a bitwise left shift. Applying this we get:

```
if(!(GPIOA->IDR & (0000 0000 0001 0000)))
```

Expanding the `IDR`, I will use `X`'s for bits that we don't care about and a `?` for the unknown bit we are testing for:

```
if(!((XXXX XXXX XXX? XXXX) & (0000 0000 0001 0000)))
```

Next we have a `&` which is the bitwise AND operator. If you remember your AND truth table:

```
&   0 1
    - -
0 | 0 0
1 | 0 1
```

So we have the operation:

```
  XXXX XXXX XXX? XXXX
& 0000 0000 0001 0000
---------------------
  0000 0000 000? 0000
```

If Bit 4 in Port A is a `0`, the the result will be `0000 0000 0000 0000`. If Bit 4 in Port A is a `1`, the the result will be `0000 0000 0001 0000`.

If the switch is pressed, the input will be pulled to GND and Bit 4 will be set to `0`. If the switch is unpressed, then the internal pull-up will pull the input high and Bit 4 will be set to `1`.

So we have two possibilities:

```
//Button is pressed
if(!(0000 0000 0000 0000))
```

Or:

```
//Button is not pressed
if(!(0000 0000 0001 0000))
```

Now it's important to understand that `!` is the **Logical** NOT operator. Which inverts `true` and `false` in conditional statements. It is also important to understand that in the [C language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Objective-C.2C_Awk.2C_Perl):

> Logical operators (`&&`, `||`, `!`, etc.) and condition-testing
>   statements (`if`, `while`) assume that zero is false and **all other
>   values are true**.

*Emphasis mine*

So what we really have is:

```
//Button is pressed
if(!(false))
```

Or:

```
//Button is not pressed
if(!(true))
```

Applying the NOT:

```
//Button is pressed
if(true)
    Key=1;
```

Or:

```
//Button is not pressed
if(false)
    Key=1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!(GPIOA->IDR & (1<<4))) Key=1;
```

is equivalent to

```
if((GPIOA->IDR & (1<<4)) == 0) Key=1;
```

In C, `!E` is equivalent to `E == 0`.

So here basically, `Key = 1;` statement is executed if the value of bit 4 of `GPIOA->IDR` is `0`.

Comment: Possibly the other missing bit of understanding here is that the input is inverting because of the pull-up.  In other words, when the switch is pressed logic 0 is presented at the GPIO input.

Answer (score 1):

Assume GPIOA->IDR is a byte.

```
[1111 1111] would infer that no GIPOA->IDR bits are cleared (grounded)
[1111 1111] & [0000 1000] = 0000 1000 => != 0
If the button was pressed...
[1111 0111] & [0000 1000] = 0000 0000 => == 0
```

Bob's Your Uncle.